# Woocommerce radio button check on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom shipping method on WooCommerce that should show a little box with information to user, only when that custom shipping method is chosen.

So far I have tried with this little code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on("change", "#shipping_method_0_my_shipping_method", function() {
        if( $("#shipping_method_0_my_shipping_method").prop('checked') == true ){
            $('.custom-box').show();
        } else {
            $('.custom-box').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And it shows the .custom-box just fine when that custom shipping method is chosen. But it does not hide it for some reason, when I choose some other shipping method?

Also it does not show the box if my custom shipping method is chosen on page load, but if I click on some other shipping method, and then my custom shipping method, it will show the box fine.

Working now perfectly. Thanks for the working solution for Томица Кораћ at below!

Comment: Can you share a link to your site, so that I can assist you further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Create reusable function to show or hide .custom-box
    function toggleCustomBox() {
        // Get id of selected input
        var selectedMethod = $('input:checked', '#shipping_method').attr('id');

        // Toggle .custom-box depending on the selected input's id
        // Replace 'shipping_method_0_my_shipping_method' with your desired id
        if (selectedMethod === 'shipping_method_0_my_shipping_method') {
            $('.custom-box').show();
        } else {
            $('.custom-box').hide();
        };
    };

    // Fire our function on page load
    $(document).ready(toggleCustomBox);

    // Fire our function on radio button change
    $('#shipping_method input:radio').change(toggleCustomBox);
});
```

Let me know if this works for you.

### Edit

I've updated the script. Please try this and let me know if it works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Create reusable function to show or hide .custom-box
    function toggleCustomBox() {
        // Get id of selected input
        var selectedMethod = $('input:checked', '#shipping_method').attr('id');

        // Toggle .custom-box depending on the selected input's id
        // Replace 'shipping_method_0_my_shipping_method' with your desired id
        if (selectedMethod === 'shipping_method_0_my_shipping_method') {
            $('.custom-box').show();
        } else {
            $('.custom-box').hide();
        };
    };

    // Fire our function on page load
    $(document).ready(toggleCustomBox);

    // Fire our function on radio button change
    $(document).on('change', '#shipping_method input:radio', toggleCustomBox);
});
```

Comment: I changed the "shipping_method_0_my_shipping_method" to my actual id, but it did not do the trick. Now it will show the .cutom-box if my shipping method is chosen by default on page load, but does not hide it if I change it to other shipping method. Also if some other shipping method is chosen by default, it wont show the .custom-box when changed to my custom shipping method. I updated the result to my webpage.

Comment: OK, I'll try to debug it on your page. But currently, no matter what shipping method I choose, nothing pops up. Do you still have your popup enabled? Also, can you tell me what actual shipping method do you want to show it for? And lastly, I don't see .custom-box class anywhere in your page's source.

Comment: Much appreciated. That box should be visible if you choose "SmartPOST" shipping method and hit "refresh" on your browser. Otherwise it does not come up. Let me know if you want some login credentials or something.. ? I added now .custom-box in the source just like its on the example.

Comment: I don't think I'll need login credentials for now, but can you please tell me where did you save the script I made for you? Is it in a separate file? If yes, what's its filename?

Comment: Yes, it is in a separate file and its called "frontend.js"

Comment: I've changed my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, thank you very much! Please let me know if there is anything I can do for you =)

Comment: Glad I could help :) Well, I sure would appreciate if you'd accept and upvote my answer :)

Comment: Cannot upvote because it seems I dont have enough reputation, but I sure did accept your answer. Thanks once again! =)

Comment: That's cool, thank you Kimmo. By the way, I can see that your .custom-box div contains a mandatory field. I think you might end up having some more issues with that. I recommend further testing your checkout form with various shipping methods selected, and if you do get any errors, don't hesitate to open another question. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, Im aware of that and still thinking about solution for that. I will open a new question in case I need help =)

Comment: Just a hint for  you, you can do it with Javascript, like so: If .custom-box is visible, then make its content be such and such. Else, empty its content.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your hint, much appreciated! I will try first myself to fix on this next issue =)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me almost two years after.

Comment: Thanks for this! Is it bad practice to put the function toggleCustomBox inside of the document.ready function? Shouldn't functions be declared out of the document ready scope? Either way its working so +1 for that!!